# xsd choice inside all with multiple choice

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, sax, multiple-choice

I have two types of requests for the same xsd:

**Request 1**

```
<REQUEST>
    <ID_CLIENTE>123456</IDCLIENTE>
    <NUMERO_TARJ>11111111111111</NUMERO_TARJ>
    <MES_VENC>04</MES_VENC>
    <ANO_VENC>18</ANO_VENC>
    <MONTO>150.00</MONTO>
</REQUEST>
```

**Request 2**

```
<REQUEST>
    <ID_CLIENTE>123456</IDCLIENTE>
    <DATOS>1112124548797987984489848468448</DATOS>
    <MONTO>150.00</MONTO>
</REQUEST>
```

The following tags are required:

- ID_CLIENTE
- MONTO

The following tags are conditional:

- DATOS
- NUMERO_TARJ
- MES_VENC
- ANO_VENC

If I send DATOS tag, I can't send NUMERO_TARJ, MES_VENC and ANO_VENC.

If I send NUMERO_TARJ, I have to send always MES_VENC and ANO_VENC but I can't send DATOS tag.

I have this XSD but it isn't correct and it doesn't validate that I want (always I must use **all** tag):

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="REQUEST">
         <xs:complexType>
             <xs:all>
                 <xs:element type="xs:long" name="ID_CLIENTE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                 <xs:element type="xs:string" name="MONTO" minOccurs="1"  maxOccurs="1"/>
                 <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="opcionales" />
             </xs:all>
         </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="opcionales" abstract="true" />
    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="DATOS" substitutionGroup="opcionales"/>
    <xs:element name="infotarjeta" substitutionGroup="opcionales">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element type="xs:long" name="TARJ_NUM" minOccurs="1"  maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="MES_VENC" minOccurs="1"  maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="ANO_VENC" minOccurs="1"  maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Please, help me to fix this XSD.

Thanks!

Comment: **Note**: (DATOS) or (TARJ_NUM and MES_VENC and ANO_VENC) is the required condition.

Comment: Is it ok for you if the order of the elements inside *<REQUEST>* is fixed? Are you using XSD 1.0 or XSD 1.1?

Comment: @sergioFC I think that the version is 1.0

Comment: ¿Can you use XSD 1.1?

Answer (score 1):

> (DATOS) or (TARJ_NUM and MES_VENC and ANO_VENC) is the required condition

This suggests you want a `choice` between an `element` and a `sequence`:

```
<xs:element name="REQUEST">
     <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element type="xs:long" name="ID_CLIENTE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
             <xs:choice>
                 <xs:element type="xs:string" name="DATOS"/>
                 <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:long" name="TARJ_NUM" minOccurs="1"  maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="MES_VENC" minOccurs="1"  maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:int" name="ANO_VENC" minOccurs="1"  maxOccurs="1"/>
                 </xs:sequence>
             </xs:choice>
             <xs:element type="xs:string" name="MONTO" minOccurs="1"  maxOccurs="1"/>
         </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This will validate both the example messages in your question.

Comment: OP said "_always I must use **all** tag_". This answer is only correct if the OP is ok with removing that restriction.

Answer (score 0):

In *XSD 1.1* you can use an assertion to do what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:element name="REQUEST">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element type="xs:long" name="ID_CLIENTE"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="MONTO"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="DATOS" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:long" name="TARJ_NUM" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="MES_VENC" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:int" name="ANO_VENC" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:all>
            <xs:assert test="(boolean(DATOS) and not(TARJ_NUM) and not(MES_VENC) and not(ANO_VENC))
                or
                (boolean(TARJ_NUM) and boolean(MES_VENC) and boolean(ANO_VENC) and not(DATOS))"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I don't know how to do it using *XSD 1.0*.

Comment: If I use **assert**, I can't execute application because it shows following exception:
`org.xml.sax.SAXNotSupportedException: the specified schema language is not supported`

Comment: @DanielB. Ok, so this answer is not valid for you, as it seems you need a XSD 1.0 solution